# Is it possible to require() the output from a binary?

Tags: node.js

I am running Node.js but want to generate the import dynamically.

I have a terminal command that returns a Node.js module

```
> echo $(my-command)

console.log("hello world")
```

Can I `require` this command from Node.js?

I have tried this approach and it works, but it feels kind of wrong:

```js
eval(require('node:child_process').execSync('my-command').toString())
```

Is there a better way to "require" something from a binary?

If it helps I am running this from the terminal and need to inject something prior to node running, so I can use Node's cli arguments

```
node -r $(my-command) ./index.js
```

Comment: Can you not write it to a temporary file?

Comment: I can, that's probably the way to go